# Invalid characters showing in order invoice PDF magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento-2.1.9

Invalid characters are showing while converting order to PDF invoice which will affect in print too.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your currency symbol is not supported by the Free LibertineFont (Magento's default font in the pdfs). Whenever an unsupported character is encountered you end up with the weird missing character symbol.

You would need to change the font to one that includes support for your currency symbol.